# how to remove constant variable in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a csv file with 10000 thousand of variables. 
I would like to remove all the variables that are constant or that their standard deviation is close to zero.

Then I would like to translate the remaining variables in a numpy ndarray.

How can I do that?

Comment: You mean like use [`drop_duplicates()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html), you could calc std deviation using `df.std` and then drop those columns, it sounds like `drop_duplicates` would do what you want

Comment: @EdChum  While df.std() is a very good starting point I am not sure that drop_duplicated is what I need. I do not want to remove any rows but the column with std=0.

Comment: You could do something like this: `df[list((df.std() > 0.1)[((df.std() > 0.1) == True)].index)]` this works but is a little ugly, this calculates the std deviation, then tests if each row (which represents a column) is True and filters False values out and turns the index (which are the columns) into a list to use as a filter

Answer (score 0):

constant_vars=[]

for col in list(df):

```
if len(df[col].value_counts())==1:

    constant_vars.append(col)
```

**or use list comprehension: **

**constant_vars=[col for col in list(df) if len(df[col].value_counts())==1]**

**df.drop(constant_vars,axis=1, inplace=True)**